# Spring MVC war deployed to karaf not working?

Tags: spring-mvc, osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

I am trying to deploy a war to karaf using pax-web.I am not seeing any errors but it is not working.
But if i go to karaf console and do a bundle:update  everything is working fine.
Is there a way to do bundle:update programatically with out connecting to karaf console and doing a bundle:update manually.

Comment: not very much info from you, since a bundle:update is working, how did you install it in the first place? Are all requirements met?

Comment: I am using karaf features.All the dependencies are specified in karaf features file.In the karaf org.apache.karaf.features.cfg all features are added to featuresBoot.What i am trying to understand is what does bundle:update do..?

Comment: bundle:update updates the bundle in question, including a refresh, so actually a refresh could also fix your issue, but this still isn't the cause of it. How is your dependency set? Do you install a certain bundle in the same set, which is a requirement for the bundle in question?